# How to change color of status bar item title in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, title, statusbar

```
//Create the NSStatusBar and set its length
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];

[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setTitle:@"myTitle"];
[statusItem setToolTip:@"myToolTip"];
[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
[statusItem setEnabled:YES];
```

How to change color of "myTitle" to blue?

Some applications like PeerGuardian change their status bar item titles to red when their lists are disabled, so I guess this is somehow possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSStatusItem`'s `-setAttributedTitle` method, and give it an `NSAttributedString` of the appropriate color:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSAttributedString* blueTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"myTitle" attributes:titleAttributes];

statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];
[statusItem setAttributedTitle:blueTitle];
[blueTitle release];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works with no problems!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 version:

```swift
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.blue]
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "myTitle", attributes: attributes)

let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
statusItem.attributedTitle = attributedText
```