# Change NSStatusBar font color and size

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a custom built statusbar in my project (macOS, Xcode 10, Cocoa, Swift).

I would like to change the font and the color of my text that will appear in the status.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private weak var mainMenu: NSMenu! 
    @IBOutlet private weak var quitMenuItem: NSMenuItem! 
    .....code....
    private let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

     
    // MARK: NSApplicationDelegate
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        .....code....
        // Set the main menu
        statusItem.menu = mainMenu
        .....code....
    }
```

Comment: The status item button has an `attributedTitle` property to customize the text with `NSAttributedString`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color of status bar item title in objective-C/Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532712/how-to-change-color-of-status-bar-item-title-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Vadian I put here the answer. (Swift 4)
Hope this help for future readers.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private weak var mainMenu: NSMenu! 
    @IBOutlet private weak var quitMenuItem: NSMenuItem! 
    .....code....
    private let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

     
    // MARK: NSApplicationDelegate
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        .....code....
        // Set the main menu
        statusItem.menu = mainMenu
        
        // change color
        let myString = "My Button Title"
        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.blue ]
        let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
        statusItem.button?.attributedTitle = myAttrString

    }
```